# Prove a surface is a plane

Tags: calculus, surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a $C''$ surface defined on an open connected set D in the UV plane. Suppose $d^2\Sigma=0$ in $D$,prove that $\Sigma$ is a plane.

I know $\Sigma$ has the form

$\Sigma(u,v)=(x_1(u,v),x_2(u,v),x_3(u,v))$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle{\frac{\partial^2 x_i}{\partial u^2}=\frac{\partial^2 x_i}{\partial v^2}=\frac{\partial^2 x_i}{\partial u\partial v}=\frac{\partial^2 x_i}{\partial v\partial u}=0}$, for $i=1,2,3$

From that I can imply that $\Sigma$ only depends in a linear way from each variable? How is the open connected hypothesis use?

Comment: Hint: Suppose $f$ is a function of one variable satisfying $f'' = 0$; is the graph of $f$ a line? An argument such as yours shows the answer is "yes" on every _interval_ (connected subset) contained in the domain of $f$. If the domain of $f$ is a disjoint union of open intervals, however, the graph of $f$ might be a union of non-collinear line segments.

Comment: If you don't assume the set is connected then you can have a different plane in any connected component. Assume open is to guarantee the existence of $d\Sigma$ and $d^2\Sigma.$